# Guest users in laravel authorization policies

Tags: php, laravel-5

I use [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#creating-policies) for user authorization. How to use policies for guest users?

Here is my code:

In controller:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Post $post)
    {
        $this->authorize($post);
        return $post->all();
    }
}
```

In policy:

```
class PostPolicy
{
    // This function executes only for authenticated users.
    // I want to use it for guest users too
    public function index(User $user)
    {            
        return $user->can('get-posts');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simpliest way is to protect with Auth middleware.
or check if user is authenticated in policy

Comment: I cant check it in policy because this function is not executed if user is not authenticated

Comment: Then protect route with Auth middleware.

Answer (score 10):

First make a new service provider:

```
php artisan make:provider GuestServiceProvider
```

Then edit GuestServiceProvider.php with this:

```
public function boot()
{
    // Laravel policies only work if the user isn't null so for guest access we need to assign a dummpy user.
    // From now on to check for guest use is_null(Auth::user()->getKey())
    if(!Auth::check()) {
        $userClass = config('auth.providers.users.model');
        Auth::setUser(new $userClass());
    }
}
```

Now Policies will work for guest users and in your policy you can check for the guest by doing:

```
if(is_null(Auth::user()->getKey())){
    // it's a guest
}
```

Which essentially means if the user doesn't have an id then its not a real user, hence must be a guest.

Comment: Functionally this works, but I have concerns about using this in a team environment with multiple developers.  It creates a pattern that developers have to somehow just *know*.  They won't though, they'll go look up behavior in Laravel docs, see that if Auth::user() returns a user that the call is authenticated, and then they will do bad things.

Answer (score 7):

In your PostPolicy change this

```
class PostPolicy{
// This function executes only for authenticated users.
// I want to use it for guest users too
public function index(User $user)
{            
    return $user->can('get-posts');
}
}
```

to:

```
class PostPolicy{
// This function executes only for authenticated users.
// I want to use it for guest users too
public function index(?User $user)
{            
    return $user->can('get-posts');
}
}
```

[source](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#guest-users)

Comment: But won't $user be null? So $user->can won't work.

Comment: The $user in your example would be null and therefore if the user was not authenticated the script would crash on "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function can() on null"

Comment: Thanks. Changing to `?User` seems to work for me. But yes, using the `can` method seems wrong.

Comment: This should be mentioned in official Laravel docs so easy to forget this! +1

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.7 now has this feature built in (with PHP >=7.1) [See the docs on the new Gate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#guest-users). For anyone using older versions, here is my solution. Make a small helper to use the `authorizeForUser` method on `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests`. It leaves all native functionality intact. Extend your controller:

```
use App\User;

public function authorizeAnyone($ability, $arguments = []) {
   list($ability, $arguments) = $this->parseAbilityAndArguments($ability, $arguments);
   return $this->authorizeForUser( auth()->user() ?? new User(), $ability, $arguments);
}
```

Then wherever you want the possibility of checking your policy against a guest, use

```
$this->authorizeAnyone();
```

instead of

```
$this->authorize();
```

If you don't want to extend your controller, you can also call (for example):

```
$this->authorizeForUser( auth()->user() ?? new User, 'index', $post );
```